Is it not possible to update the global variable defined in karate-config.js
I have a scenario where I want to set the header Auth token once in Karate-config.js.
However, after a long run when the token expires, I am not find any way to reset or update the same variable so that I update the fresh token to next set of executions.
Also, please note, there is no attribute with which we will know the expiry time until it actually expired when used on the actual API callout and fails with 401 error.
Auth token refresh mechanism as a global variable to be used across all scenarios.
